# Sequential logging in concurrent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a block of async code that runs concurrently which also contains logging statements.

```js
async function processItems(item) {
   console.log("Start", item)
   await doSomethingAsync(item)
   console.log("First")
   await doSomethingAsync(item)
   console.log("Second")
   await doSomethingAsync(item)
   console.log("Stop", item)
}

await Promise.all(someItems.map(processItems));
```

Since the blocks run concurrently, the log messages of a single function call are not in sequence anymore.

How could I show a sequential log while still letting the code run in parallel?

Comment: You can't have two opposite things at the same time. Showing a sequential log means that the code doesn't run in parallel. Running the code in parallel means that the logs are not sequential.

Comment: Also, _"the log messages of a single function call are not in sequence anymore"_ is not true. The logs of a single item should be in sequence

Comment: Send a sequence number to your `doSomethingAsync(item, seqNum)` and backend ajax handler. Just have your backend regurgitate the given seqNum value back in it's response and then assemble the log messages using append/prepend as needed.  What is the "log" you are using, eg: text, html ordred list, etc?

Comment: You should log the item identifier (or just the iteration index) with each console message.